# Multiple key listeners with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, dom-events, addeventlistener, keyboard-events

I have a physics engine, which updates with every frame, and I have a vehicle with wheels which I would like to control by using some arrow keys.

As a brute force method, I created 4 `Listeners`, one for each arrow key like that:

when a key is pressed...

```
    fromEvent(document, KEY_DOWN)
          .pipe(
            filter(e => e.keyCode === KEYS.UP),
            filter(e => !e.repeat)
          )
          .subscribe(() => {
            ...
            updateSpeed(...)
          });
```

and when a key is released...

```
 fromEvent(document, KEY_UP)
      .pipe(filter(e => e.keyCode === KEYS.UP))
      .subscribe(() => {
        ...
      updateSpeed(...) // set speed back to 0
      });
```

It works but it looks tedious as I have to create a `keydown` listener and a `keyup` listener for every key (8 listeners in total). 
Is there any way to merge the events, have a single and more elegant controller?

Comment: Here a couple of articles around the same theme, if I got it right, which you may find interesting "https://medium.com/free-code-camp/thinking-reactively-how-to-animate-with-movement-objects-using-rxjs-692518b6f2ac"and "https://medium.com/free-code-camp/reactive-thinking-how-to-design-a-distributed-system-with-rxjs-websockets-and-node-57d772f89260"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should look into the `combineLatest` or one of the combinnation operators (https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom).

This is not a complete answer but something to get you started

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
...
x = combineLatest(
  fromEvent(document, KEY_DOWN).pipe(
    filter(e => e.keyCode === KEYS.UP || /* Allow the other 3 keys with or statements */),
    filter(e => !e.repeat),
    startWith(null),
  ),
  fromEvent(document, KEY_UP).pipe(
    filter(e => e.keyCode === KEYS.UP || /* Allow the other 3 keys with or statements */)),
    startWith(null),
  )
).subscribe(([keyDown, keyUp]) => {
    // you have access to keyDown and keyUp events here. Make sure they are truthy since we startWith null and see their values and do the appropriate actions
  });

....
x.unsubscribe();
```

I `startWith` null because `combineLatest`, each observable has to emit at least once for the stream to start so this will start the stream. You may have to play around to get the desired results.

Also, since you are subscribing to `events`, it is very important for you to `unsubscribe` from the subscription because events are not finite and this can lead to unintinded behaviour (The subscription reacting to every key button even though this code is not "alive").

============================ Edit ======================
I think `merge` is even a better way.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

x = merge(
  fromEvent(document, KEY_DOWN).pipe(
    filter(e => e.keyCode === KEYS.UP || /* Allow the other 3 keys with or statements */),
    filter(e => !e.repeat),
  ),
  fromEvent(document, KEY_UP).pipe(
    filter(e => e.keyCode === KEYS.UP || /* Allow the other 3 keys with or statements */)),
  )
).subscribe(keyUpOrKeyDown => {
  // now you have a handle on the event and can do the appropriate action accordingly
});
....
x.unsubscribe();
```

This way I find is better since you won't need `startWith(null)`

Comment: That works, thanks, I prefer the second implementation.